# How to get AMD graphics card working on kernel 3.10.x?

Tags: drivers, ati, kernel

I'm running **Kubuntu 13.04_x64** on my *Sony Vaio SVE171E13L*.  The notebook has an *AMD Radeon HD7650M* graphics card.  Up until now, I've been using the AMD proprietary driver (**AMD Catalyst 13.4**).

After building the 3.10 (now 3.10.1) kernel, however, I no longer had a graphical interface!

It turns out that 3.10 has introduced a major change in the /proc filesystem API.  (According to the bug report for broken fglrx driver.)

The fglrx driver no longer builds.  I tried purging the proprietary driver and installing the open source driver with no success.  In retrospect, that's not surprising, as the open source driver is an older version of the AMD driver.

I also tried the beta Catayst 13.6, but that didn't work either.  That version predates the kernel as well.

Has *anyone* found a way to get an AMD graphics card working with this kernel?!?

I've searched and searched, but I've been unable to find *anything* that will help me get this working!  In fact, I've barely found any references to this issue at all!

**Surely** this kernel wasn't released knowing that **everyone**  with an AMD graphics card would be unable to use it!!!

Thanks for any suggestions!

**EDIT: 7/21/2013**

I wanted to clarify in response to @edwin's comment...  This isn't a *bug*, per se, although I did see that someone had filed a bug report.

From what I read on the issue, it's simply a matter that that there was a somewhat major change in kernel 3.10, and the AMD driver hasn't been updated to deal with it.

I'm simply asking if anyone with an AMD graphics card has **successfully** built 3.10, and, if so, ***how***?!?

Comment: What do you mean by *development*?  As far as I knew, 13.04 is the mainstream version!  I don't need the long term support version.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused. I mean that the kernel version is not the official one for Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually caved with similar problems and started using the open source radeon driver.  I have a post on Ubuntu Forums, but the site is down now, on how to enable that drivers power saving features. If performed decent FPS and the temperature of the cpu was about the same running fglrx.

Purge the proprietary driver. 
move /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Go here for the rest: I used this to make my post on Ubuntu Forums

http://www.techytalk.info/ubuntu-open-source-ati-radeon-driver-power-usage-tweaks/

or for more explanation of the two methods and help you choose:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ATI